# 2 histograms with common x-axis are not aligned

Tags: tikz-pgf, bar-chart

I have to following latex code:

```
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfopts}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]
\begin{axis}[minor tick num=1,
            scale only axis,
            height=5cm,
            width=\textwidth*0.8,
            xlabel=\textnumero contestants,
            ylabel style={overlay},
                yticklabel style={overlay},
            xticklabel style={overlay},
            ylabel=,
            ybar,
            ymin=0,
            legend style={at={(0, 1)},anchor=west},
            legend entries={\textnumero matches, \textnumero rounds}]
\addplot [draw opacity=0,fill=yellow!50] table [x index=0, y index=1] {charts/merge_no_matches_rounds.csv};
\addplot [draw opacity=0,fill=green] table [x index=0, y index=2] {charts/merge_no_matches_rounds.csv};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This is the result:
[image: Result]

The data file looks like this:

```
2   1   1
4   4   3
6   9   6
8   11  6
10  17  9
12  21  9
14  23  9
. . .
92  181 18
94  185 18
96  189 18
98  191 18
100 193 18
```

The yellow area looks fine, but the green one has a weird offset. How can I resolve this?

Comment: Welcome to TeX SE! Please complete your code to make it compilable. A small, compilable document showing the issue makes it much easier to help and more likely you'll get useful answers.

Comment: Thanks for the notice. I've updated my code. Please indicate if you're still having issues with the compilation.

Comment: Does `ybar=stacked` do what you want?  Also, please try cutting and pasting the code posted here and make sure it compiles.

Comment: @PeterGrill The two areas are now aligned nicely on top of each other, however the top one is now moved up, so it actually shows the value of y1 + y2. I need a stacked view without adding them. In worst case, I'll just prepare my data so that y2 = y2_old - y1, but I hope, there's a nicer solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not use a histogram here. If one value of the yellow data gets lower than the corresponding green value, your idea of plot is not practical any more. You should use real bars or real stacking, not a mix. (in reality, simple curves would be the best)

Still, I provide a solution for you:

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{charts/merge_no_matches_rounds.csv}
    2   1   1
    4   4   3
    6   9   6
    8   11  6
    10  17  9
    12  21  9
    14  23  9
    92  181 18
    94  185 18
    96  189 18
    98  191 18
    100 193 18
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}
        \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[%
    ,minor tick num=1
    ,scale only axis
    ,height=5cm
    ,width=\textwidth*0.8
    ,xlabel=\textnumero{} contestants
    ,yticklabel style={overlay}
    ,xticklabel style={overlay}
    ,ymin=0
    ,legend cell align=left
    ,legend style={at={(0, 1)},anchor=west}]
    \addplot [draw opacity=0,name path=f,area legend,fill=yellow!50] table [x index=0, y index=1] {charts/merge_no_matches_rounds.csv};
    \addplot [draw opacity=0,name path=g,area legend,fill=green] table [x index=0, y index=2] {charts/merge_no_matches_rounds.csv};
    \path[name path=axis] (axis cs:0,0.2) -- (axis cs:100,0.2);
    \addplot [draw opacity=0,color=yellow!50,fill=yellow!50]
    fill between[of=f and axis];
    \addlegendentry{\textnumero{} matches}
    \addplot [draw opacity=0,color=green,fill=green]
    fill between[of=g and axis];
    \addlegendentry{\textnumero{} rounds}
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{figure}    
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your effort. However, I'll take your advice and use curves instead, my original idea would be ambiguous for the readers. Thank you once more :)

Comment: @DavidFrank Glad I could help. You are welcome.